# file_put_contents with owners file

Tags: php

I have some problems with the owners for this file, which owner had necessary ?

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/home/web/papier.com/ftp/www/wp-    content/plugins/menu_css3/less/variables.less) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open     stream: Permission denied in /home/web/papier.com/ftp/www/wp-    content/plugins/menu_css3/panel.php on line 234

file_put_contents(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/menu_css3/less/variables.less' , $less);
```

I changed everything for nobody and nogroup, but with root nothing works on the web ?

this is my ls -al

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 03:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 01:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 01:05 .git
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup    18 Feb 12 02:31 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  1177 Feb 12 01:00 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  3258 Feb 12 01:00 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  1055 Feb 12 01:00 LICENSE-MIT
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup   361 Feb 12 01:00 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 7 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 01:00 assets
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 01:00 bootstrap-tour
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup   126 Feb 12 01:00 bower.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nogroup 87237 Feb 12 01:00 elements.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup   144 Feb 12 01:00 info.json
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 01:00 lang
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 01:00 less
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  1663 Feb 12 01:00 nav.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nogroup   537 Feb 12 01:00 package.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nogroup 95617 Feb 12 03:15 panel.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  1613 Feb 12 01:00 readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nogroup  1158 Feb 12 01:00 uninstall.php
drwxr-xr-x 9 nobody nogroup  4096 Feb 12 01:00 widgets
root@vds1074:/home/web/xavier-artot.com/ftp/www/wp-content/plugins/menu_css3#
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no way for us to know how your file system permissions are set up. You'll have to `ls -l` the file and figure it out yourself.

Comment: commonly after ls -l, check what are the rest of the file owner looks like then just do a quick chown <name>:<name> <filename> to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Change all the parents directory aswell.
If you have symlink, change the symlink origiral directory permission.

Comment: I don't undestand your response, I did and I changed, but for wich user and group ?

Comment: Depends on your apache or web user. 
For ubuntu/apache2 it would be www-data.
[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=880698] for reference.